# make: pattern rule matching multiple extensions

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have duplicated pattern rules for several extensions (eg: `cpp` and `cc`):

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I. -o $@ -c $?

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I. -o $@ -c $?
```

Is there a way to have one pattern rule which matches on both extensions, rather than having to have two rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) for this. Here's an executable example:

```
OBJ_DIR:=obj
SRC_DIR:=src

TARGETS:=obj/foo.o obj/bar.o

all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp) $$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc)
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I. -o $@ -c $<
```

Create `src/foo.cc` and `src/bar.cpp`, and issue `make -n`, and you'll get:

```
g++  -I. -o obj/foo.o -c src/foo.cc
g++  -I. -o obj/bar.o -c src/bar.cpp
```

If you have both `foo.cc` and `foo.cpp` this will behave just like the version in the question asked here (`foo.cpp` will have precedence over `foo.cc`, which will be ignored).

The `$` signs are doubled for `$$(wildcard...` to prevent evaluation during the first expansion. You could have `$$(SRC_DIR)` just as well as `$(SRC_DIR)` since it does not matter (in the code above) when this variable is expanded.

Comment: I don't kn ow about you, but this looks like black magic to me, and I've been using `make` on and off for the past 30 years.

Comment: Does this actually work? I'd have expected this to need to be more like `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $$(wildcard $$(SRC_DIR)/$$*.cpp) $$(wildcard $$(SRC_DIR)/$$*.cc)` To wildcard on the matched stem. Also I wonder if this might have problems in more complicated scenarios. But it is clever.

Comment: @EtanReisner Did you try it? I did.

Comment: No, hence the question. I don't have a good model for when patterns are matched... oh, I see what this is doing I think. The pattern expands first and then wildcard just drops a path that doesn't exist. I was thinking about it the other way (which didn't make sense).

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't combine the two rules. Prerequisites all have to match.

But you can avoid needing to have the recipe specified twice.

Either by using a define for the recipe:

```
define COMPILE
@$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I. -o $@ -c $?
endef

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        $(COMPILE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
        $(COMPILE)
```

Or by using a loop and eval to define the recipes (untested I may have gotten some of the escaping wrong but I prefer the define approach anyway):

```
$(foreach prereq,cc cpp,$(eval $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(prereq) ; @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I. -o $@ -c $?))
```

Comment: Accepted @Louis's answer, as it is technically correct, even though the syntax requirements for `.SECONDEXPANSION` mean I'll use your approach.

Comment: The advantage of the "foreach" approach, is that it can be generalized for multiple extensions (think: image formats). I expanded on this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857821/193789).