# Makefile: operate on all files in a subdirectory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a Makefile and GNU make to create various document output targets based on a source Markdown file.

This includes using `latex` or `pdflatex` to create a DVI file.  Use of images in other than EPS or PS formats causes errors.

I can search-and-replace image names within the source markdown file, and have done so.

What I'd like to do is create a makefile rule for all image files in the `images/` subdirectory, and to run `convert` to create eps versions of those files.

So:

```
images/myimage1.png
images/myimage2.jpeg
```

Are retained, but have additional versions created:

```
images/myimage1.eps
images/myimage2.eps
```

(And yes, I've got to keep track otherwise that there aren't name collisions elsewhere.)

The command to be run would be something like:

```
convert -format eps images/myimage1.png images/myimage1.eps
```

I'd want to run this on any non-EPS image files:  gif, jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, etc.  These will be specifically listed in the Makefile.

---

### And here's the first iteration

It works (modulo other errors), though it's a bit long, and if extended
to the full 193 graphics formats supported by Imagemagick would be ...
unweildy.

My goal here is to build the DVI, so I'm showing the related targets

```
dvi: docfs-Manifesto.dvi
latex: docfs-Manifesto.tex
epsimg.md: docfs-Manifesto.md

docfs-Manifesto.tex: docfs-Manifesto-epsimg.md all-img 
    pandoc -s --from=markdown --to=latex -o docfs-Manifesto.tex docfs-Manifesto-epsimg.md

docfs-Manifesto-epsimg.md: docfs-Manifesto.md
    ./img-ref-to-eps.sed docfs-Manifesto.md > docfs-Manifesto-epsimg.md

docfs-Manifesto.dvi: latex
    pdflatex -output-format dvi -halt-on-error docfs-Manifesto.tex 2>pdflatex.log

MG_DIR=images
EPS_DIR=images-eps

# We can handle any of about 193 formats Imagemagick will read, but
# let's start with some basics

# ... Source formats
SRC_GIF = $(wildcard $(IMG_DIR)/*.gif)
SRC_JPG = $(wildcard $(IMG_DIR)/*.jpg)

# ... Destination formats
EPS_GIF = $(patsubst $(IMG_DIR)/%.gif,$(EPS_DIR)/%.eps,$(SRC_GIF))
EPS_JPG = $(patsubst $(IMG_DIR)/%.jpg,$(EPS_DIR)/%.eps,$(SRC_JPG))


# And the actual conversions.  This ... could be shorter?

all-img: $(EPS_DIR) $(EPS_GIF) $(EPS_JPG) 
    @echo "Done"

$(EPS_DIR) :
    mkdir $(EPS_DIR)

$(EPS_DIR)/%.eps : $(IMG_DIR)/%.gif
    convert -format eps $< $@

$(EPS_DIR)/%.eps : $(IMG_DIR)/%.jpg
    convert -format eps $< $@
```

(I think that's all the relevant rules)

And it succceeds, in that it fails with an image my conversion script
had failed to convert.

But that's not Make's fault.

---

### Now tackling the code length via a foreach loop

And we've got it!  77 lines of code reduced to 17 (inclusive of whitespace).

```
IMG_DIR=images
EPS_DIR=images-eps

# We can handle any of about 193 formats Imagemagick will read, but
# let's start with some basics
# Thanks @kebs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857821/9105048

IMG_EXT=bmp dot gif jpg jpeg png raw tiff xcf pnm ppm ps

# ... Source formats

IMG_FILES = $(wildcard $(IMG_DIR)/*)

# Rename files s/./_/ so: img1.gif => img1_gif Then add extension

IMG_FILES2 = $(subst .,_,$(IMG_FILES))

EPS_FILES = $(patsubst $(IMG_DIR)/%,$(EPS_DIR)/%.eps,$(IMG_FILES2))

all-img: $(EPS_DIR) $(EPS_FILES)
@echo "all-img: done"

$(EPS_DIR) :
    mkdir $(EPS_DIR)

$(foreach \
prereq, \
$(IMG_EXT), \
$(eval $(EPS_DIR)/%_$(prereq).eps: $(IMG_SRC)/%.$(prereq); convert -format eps $$< $$@) \
)
```

Current output (following `make clean`):

```
$ make all-img
convert -format eps images/browser-of-a-scientist.jpg images-eps/browser-of-a-scientist_jpg.eps
convert -format eps images/nukewaste.jpg images-eps/nukewaste_jpg.eps
convert -format eps images/standards.png images-eps/standards_png.eps
$ ls images-eps/
browser-of-a-scientist_jpg.eps standards_png.eps
nukewaste_jpg.eps
```

Comment: Okay, so you need some wildcard matching and pattern rules. But before going further, could you show us the code you already have ?

Comment: @kebs:  there's no code relevant to the question here.  I've got a Makefile that generates most of my desired outputs, though the DVI generator fails as noted due to use of JPG and PNG files.  Directory structure is `docs` with a markdown file, and an `images/` subdirectory.  I've got the Imagemagick code I'm running in shell right now as shown.

Comment: To check the variables, add a rule (say, `print:`) with no dependencies and that has `@echo $(SRC_GIF); @echo $(EPS_GIF)` as recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SRC_DIR=images
SRC_FILES1 = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.png)
SRC_FILES2 = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.jpeg)

DEST_FILES1 = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.png,$(SRC_DIR)/%.eps,$(SRC_FILES1))
DEST_FILES2 = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.jpeg,$(SRC_DIR)/%.eps,$(SRC_FILES2))

all: $(DEST_FILES1) $(DEST_FILES2)
     @echo "Done"

$(SRC_DIR)/%.eps : $(SRC_DIR)/%.png
    convert -format eps $< $@

$(SRC_DIR)/%.eps : $(SRC_DIR)/%.jpeg
    convert -format eps $< $@
```

However, this will fail if you have both `image1.png` and `image1.jpeg`.

To process other image types, you will need to replicate the rules and variables for the other image types. But I think this could be avoided if you build the eps files in another folder (which is BTW recommended, it's called an "out of source" build, the main idea is you don't mix source files and build files in the same folder). If you do so, I think you can manage to have only one variable and build rule.

---

**EDIT** ok, I think I have a solution to simplify all that:

First, define a variable holding all the needed file types (read: extensions):

```
EXT=gif png jpg jpeg
```

Then, build a variable holding ALL your images (assuming there are only images here, this is requested):

```
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*)
```

Then we need to build the corresponding target variables holding all the input files, but with .eps extension. We can't use `patsubst` directly because it cannot proceed with multiples extensions. So we need a trick: replace `img1.gif` by `img1_gif` and then add the .eps extension. This is done in two steps:

First, replace `.` by `_` in the input files:

```
DEST1 = $(subst .,_,$(SRC_FILES))
```

Second, add the .eps extension (assuming the output folder is `out`):

```
DEST2 = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,out/%.eps,$(DEST1))
```

Ok, now we are done:

```
all: $(DEST2)
    @echo "Done"
```

Well, not quite. Here comes the final trick: use the `foreach` function to generate automatically all the needed recipes from the `EXT` variable:

```
$(foreach \
    prereq, \
    $(EXT), \
    $(eval out/%_$(prereq).eps: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(prereq); convert -format eps $$< $$@) \
)
```

This will instanciate in `prereq` all the values in `EXT` and call the `eval` function to generate the recipe.

Comment: So, what might a good OOS location be?  A subdir, "images/eps"?  Or a parallel dir, say images/ and eps/?

Comment: An alternative to the name-collision problem would be to rename the files _including_ the source extension, so:  myimage1.png => myimage1.png.eps.  Awkward but safer.

Comment: I'm working off this, with some expansion.  Turns out there are about 193 possible image file conversions, so rationalising those down the road might make sense (based off `identify -list format`).  For now I've 12 formats (bmp, dot, gif, jpg, jpeg, png, raw, tiff, xcf, pnm, ppm, ps), which is plenty.  Also, if I'm going to update my question with the makefile I've got, what's the standard practice around these parts?

Comment: `what might a good OOS location be? ` Definitely the second choice, making the output folder a subfolder of the source on is a bad approach.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That does turn out to be the basis for a functioning solution.

Comment: Good, then I've chosen my output location wisely :)  Any suggestions on making the whole conversion / format selection ... shorter?  I've got 12 formats I'm playing with for now, and that's likely to get longer.  Though there might well be some format-specific Imagemagick manipulations I'd want to do as well.

Comment: That loop / rename is slick.  Thanks.  With whitespace, 77 lines to 18.  Except that it's not working :(  Any debug tips?

Comment: And:  sorted the first set of issues, missing some necessary spaces.  Expressions are being generated but not executed AFAICT, see post.

Comment: Doh!  The @echo does just that:  echos output.  Probably something you had inserted for testing.  Removed that (see my last version above) and we're cooking on gas.  Thanks, I've learnt a lot.

Comment: As things go, that wasn't a bad trap to leave for me.  I figured it out, learned something, and have a better understanding of how all this works.  I really can't thank you enough, this has been quite helpful.